# How to make an infinite scroll in Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've tried with will_paginate_infinite, jquery-infinite-pages and anyone of them could solve my problem.
Tell me other gems for rails or another forms to do it.
Rails 4.2

Comment: Your question is getting down-voted because it is basically asking other people to do all the work for you. It's also worded in such a way as to get very subjective responses. A better question would be to post the code from your latest attempt, then we can see if you might be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be several ways, I personally have done it using `jquery-infinite-pages` along with `Kaminari` gem. (In the GitHub page of jquery-infinite-page` they actually have an example of this).

Comment: I'm using this gem right now, but I can't finish it, because it doesn't realize the last step of the .js.coffee. How do I connect this file ???

Comment: Are you using `turbolinks`?  If so, check this [PR](https://github.com/magoosh/jquery-infinite-pages/pull/24), it solved the issue for me... Just use that file instead of the file from the plugin installation (you put the file in `vendor/assets/javascripts)

Comment: For your next questions, you need to provide more information (show your code, what is the error, etc...). Otherwise we have to guess what your problem is